# Vba automation click the "Input" button in this script

Tags: vba, automation

I have been trying without success to click this button on GPS Vizualizer, I have tried a couple of methods including after setting up my dims etc and setting to the document..;
No success, what am I missing, can anyone help, thanks

```
With doc.all("input")
    .focus
    .OnClick
End With
```

HTML:

```
<input style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 3px;" 
  onclick="this.form.action='http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map?output_geocoder'; document.map_form.special.value='geocoder'; this.form.submit();" 
   type="button" value="Draw a map">
```

Comment: If there's only one button then use `doc.getElementsByTagName(0)` to refer to the button.  If there are multiple buttons then loop over them until you find the one with Value "Draw a Map"

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have tried similar code to this and made other attempts following your reply without success,  would you expand a little more on how you would achive this?

Comment: Sure - care to share a little more code though, including a URL ?

Comment: gps visualizer http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.document.querySelector("input[onclick*='this.form.action']")
```

[image: CSS query]

It uses the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of the `document` to apply a css selector which looks for `input` tag containing attribute `onclick`, which contains string `'this.form.action'`

You can also use:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(8).Click
```

The following worked:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("input[onclick*='this.form.action']").Click
       ' .document.getElementsByTagName("input")(8).Click

       Stop '<==Delete me
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is my code, it adds a recordset to apply input details and set a couple of items and output this to make the map. I have added QHarr's code but i get a runtime error.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't meant to go

Comment: yes, i have been doing this manually and it works great, I am working towards hiding iE and delivering the map as a downloa which certainly looks do-able

Comment: Thanks, I dont get the runtime error but it still wont click the darn button. If you have a moment can you inspect the page?

Comment: I have. The code I posted works. It clicks the button and the page changes. Both methods I listed I tested. It takes you to a draw map page.

Comment: Did you try both methods I listed?

Comment: Thats good to know, the reference was already in the library.

Comment: Thanks all, I have tried your solutions and got them to work to the extent that they opened the default page selected but they didn't take along the map information.

Comment: I tried tagname "a"(29) it seems relevant? and I get a message asking for the api key, inspecting there is "format" element too, seems like a squence I cant figure with my limited knowledge.

Comment: Then that is a different question in my opinion as this does click that button. I would suggest a new question (linking to this) saying that does click but information is not carried across and asking how to do that. That may be more difficult if people need an account, for example, to debug. Will such information be required?

Answer (score 0):

[runtime error screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06d1U.png)

```
Set doc = IE.Document
With doc
doc.getElementById("google_key_box").Value = "Api Key here"
doc.getElementById("geocode_input").focus
doc.getElementById("geocode_input").Value = retVal
End With
With doc.all("data_source")

                                .focus
                                .Value = "google"
                                .OnChange
                                End With
With doc.all("start")

                                .focus
                                .OnClick
                                End With

doc.querySelector("input[onclick*=this.form.action='http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map? 
output_geocoder';]").Click
```

Comment: The code sets a drop box so a google map is used followed by a button click to code coordinates, Your code would draw the map, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It should click on that button and open a new tab.

```
Sub ClickONButton()
    Const url As String = "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument, R&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With
    Html.querySelector("input[value='Draw a map']").Click
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: I suppose you are using latest version of `IE` @GMan63.